# Valid xpath has not worked

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using ,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//A[@href='/BLBP/custNewHome'][text()='New Customer']")).click();
```

and I have check path value is right.

But it is not working what can I do now?

Output :
[image]
It is a dropdown menu.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Put some `wait` before the given step, if your `xpath` is correct .Or else share html code

Comment: It is **not** valid. How did you check it?

Comment: `//*[contains(text(),'New Customer')]` this will work. It would be great if you share html code for precise `xpath`

Comment: @KishanPatel I have added . Plz Chcek

Comment: @MarkLapierre I have added . Plz Chcek

Comment: `//a[contains(text(),'New Customer')]` Have you tried this ?

Comment: The xpath in the screenshot is different from the xpath in your code. As @G_H's answer shows. It's the kind of typo that we've all made at some point, but next time you might benefit from double-checking your code and save yourself the trouble of asking on SO.

Comment: your xpath is broken. seems like there are extra parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//A[@href='/BLBP/custNewHome'][text()='New Customer']"))`

Look carefully and strip away parentheses one by one. First the `findElement` method invocation.

`By.xpath("(//A[@href='/BLBP/custNewHome'][text()='New Customer']")`

Next the `xpath` invocation.

`"(//A[@href='/BLBP/custNewHome'][text()='New Customer']"`

The string that remains is your xpath expression. Notice how it has an open parentheses at the start but no closing parentheses at the end. There's the issue.

Use this:

`"//A[@href='/BLBP/custNewHome'][text()='New Customer']"`

or this:

`"(//A[@href='/BLBP/custNewHome'][text()='New Customer'])"`

Comment: @TanmoyRay I fail to see how much more complete I can make this answer. You've got a parentheses , the `(` thing, too much at the start of your xpath. Either remove that, or add a `)` at the end.

Comment: I am new in it, I like to click this element what can i do now?

Comment: @TanmoyRay What you can do is exactly what I said: fix your incorrect xpath which is syntactically invalid because it has unmatched parentheses. This is an open parentheses : **`(`** This is a close parentheses: **`)`**. You have an open at the start of your xpath, but not a corresponding close at the end. Either add the close parentheses, or remove the open. Please tell me I don't have to spell this out further because it's the most basic of programming knowledge.

Comment: Thank you, I have slipped these parentheses :( Sorry